# Установка видеодрайвера для AMD на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux

Ubuntu устанавливается только с nomodeset, после чего интерфейс сильно тормозит и превращается в "слайдшоу"(мышь телепортируется, медленное обновление экрана)
Вычитал, что дело в видеодрайвере, но не знаю как его установить.

Ноутбук Dell Inspiron 15 5567
Intel Core i5 7200U
AMD Radeon R7 M440 4 ГБ

Comment: Чё `ubuntu-drivers list` выдаёт?

Comment: Пакет называется xf86-video-amdgpu - пользуйтесь гуглом

Comment: @donRumata пусто, совсем

Comment: @Beeen007 загуглил, но не разобрался как установить

Comment: @Surv ну надо разобраться ) инфы валом

Comment: @Beeen007, я тока `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` нашёл.